# How to setup GA E-Commerce Tracking in DTM

Tags: google-analytics, adobe-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

Currently, I am trying to setup GA E-Commerce Tracking in Adobe DTM. Unfortunately, there is no documentation about that, and the answer in following post, doesn't work for me: [Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce in Adobe DTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351024/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-in-adobe-dtm)
My rule is firing but it looks like the ga script is not loaded. Any suggestions on best practices to set up GA E-Commerce in DTM?

Comment: The answer provided in the link you posted is still relevant, though it could be made a little more clear. It showed it in the code example an explicit `dtm_ga_standard` namespace used, so make sure you change the namespace in the GA tool to that (or whatever namespace you prefer).  Otherwise DTM will use an internally generated namespace that you can't easily reference in the code later on.

Comment: @CrayonViolent , I removed the entire dtm_ga_ part to ensure that there are no namespace issues, but it's still not working. It seems like DTM can't read the third party code: ga('standard.ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
      id: dtm Data Element,
      revenue: dtm Data Element
    });
ga('standard.send', 'pageview');

Comment: okay, so did you (re)name your namespace to `standard` in the GA tool config?

Comment: also can i assume that `dtm Data Element` is just pseudo-code or is that what you actually have? because that's not valid syntax. Perhaps I could provide more help if you provide details about what exactly you have implemented and where.